# coexistence of legacy WSL and ubuntu

Tags: windows

i have enabled in the past WSl. Meanwhile I have installed the ubuntu app from the windows store. Now I have both folder \wsl$\Legacy and \wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04.

My question: how to force Visual Studio Code to point to the ubuntu terminal?

I don't need the legacy system more. Is it possible to uninstall it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: That sounds like a question about Windows rather than about Ubuntu

Comment: starting vscode (code) from the ubuntu terminal (ubuntu app) resolves the problem. A terminal can be opened when selecting a folder and right click on it and "open in terminal".